# Visual Studio Setup project - force installation of a .DLL?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer

I have an update to third party .DLL that must be installed onto my clients' computers.  We currently employ automated installs via MSI that are created in Visual Studio 2010

Unfortunately, the third party .DLL was versioned incorrectly and file version of it was not increased by the provider (they only increased assembly version).  The third party provider is Microsoft, so waiting on them to fix the issue is not realistic.  We need to get the new .DLL to people now and within one MSI update.  Right now, MSI update is not overriding the .DLL

Is there a way within VS2010 Setup project to force override a .DLL even if the file versions match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to do msi postbuild tweaking you can hit the File table and do "version lying".  Another thought is to not put that DLL in your install.  Find an installer from Microsoft ( if it exists ) that you can put into a bootstrapper or create your own installer and use AMUS instead of OMUS for the version rules.

Comment: Can't NOT include the .DLL into the package.  No MSM to work with and I can't change switch install parameters anyway.  The auto-updating code is already running in the field.  When it runs, it runs with the command line that basically does a silent upgrade.  Can you elaborate on the "version lying"?

Comment: Version Lying is where you update the File Table to trick MSI into thinking it has a newer version then it actually has.  There's some minor gotchas but basically it'll give you an Always Overwrite for a single component.   The real solution is to follow proper SCM practices with your resources ( yes, sad that it's Microsoft we are talking about here ).

Comment: Appreciate the further elaboration, but I'm not sure how to approach the problem of switching versions programmatically.  Google wasn't much of help.  Can you provide a link with some instructions as to how would one go about this?  Thanks

Comment: You have to do something like the following only do it to the File Table.  FWIW, this is one of the many, many reasons that I never use VDPROJ.  It's far too limited in it's capabilities. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/05/28/2958062.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add the file to your installer as a 'file' and install it with the other files? Don't set it as project output, or any of the canned install actions. Go to the file portion and right click the "Application Files" folder, and say > add file. Navigate to the file that you want and choose it.

Comment: No.  MSI has a process called File Costing that looks as the File Version ( AssemblyFileVersion ) not the AssemblyVersion attribute.  If the old version and new version of the DLL have the same version number, MSI won't overwrite it even if they are different.

Comment: Even if you EXPLICITLY tell it to copy the file? You could create a custom installer class, to copy the dll from a temp folder the MSI creates, and then delete that once you've copied it? It's getting that icky feeling now though.....

Comment: I tried putting the file into the package as a regular file and excluding it from the outputs.  It didn't get deployed over the older version.

Comment: Use an installer class? Why didn't I think of that? <sarcasm/>